# Emscriptem fails to build sample, wants /usr/bin/opt

Tags: compilation, ubuntu-13.10, emscripten, asm.js

I installed Emscripten using the instructions [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Ubuntu-12.10), with a few differences for 13.10:

Instead of compiling and setting up clang 3.2, installed from the repository since it's 3.2. (`clang --version` shows expected output)

Linked the llvm since the compiler didn't find it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-link-3.2 /usr/bin/llvm-link
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-ar-3.2 /usr/bin/llvm-ar
```

But now I get an error about the nonexistence of /usr/bin/opt, even though ~/.emscripten has no mention of that directory:

```
$ ./em++ tests/hello_world.cpp
WARNING  root: LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "version", expected "3.2")
INFO     root: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
CRITICAL root: Cannot find /usr/bin/opt, check the paths in ~/.emscripten
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2101), there were several more that needed links from -3.2 to normal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check /usr/bin installed files from llvm-3.2 package:

   ```
   dpkg -L llvm-3.2 | grep /usr/bin/ | sort
   ```
2. Create sym-links without version number

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-ar-3.2 /usr/bin/llvm-ar
   ...
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/opt-3.2 /usr/bin/opt
   ```

   Note: Don't forget 5 files named no include "llvm-". ( bugpoint, c-index-test, llc, macho-dump, opt)
3. Check /usr/bin installed files from llvm-3.2-runtime package:

   ```
   dpkg -L llvm-3.2-runtime | grep /usr/bin/ | sort
   ```
4. Create sym-link without version number:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/lli-3.2 /usr/bin/lli
   ```
5. Run Emscripten:

   ```
   emcc
   ```